# Не запускается телеграмм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pycharm

Запускал на двух разных ПК. На одном запускается нормально, без ошибок. Второй пк запускает вот с такой ошибкой.
Она вылазит сразу после запуска, в независимости от взаимодействия с самим ботом. 
Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?
Заранее спасибо.
[image: На втором выдаёт такую ошибку]

Comment: На втором компьютере может быть не загружен python. Если он скачан то может он старой версии. Я конечно не так хорошо разбираюсь, но может быть поможет!

Comment: перепроверил, последняя версия.

Comment: Может проблема подключение бота к серверу? Если это не так то извините я в ботах не разбираюсь.. Или проблема может быть в pycharm'e. У меня были баги с pycharm

Comment: Проблемы с подключением к серверу быть в принципе не может. ПК и выполняет функцию сервера.

Comment: вы используете в коде подключение к БД?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что не удалось разрезолвить адрес хоста.

Раз вопрос задан 14.02.2020 и осуществляется попытка подключения к серверам Telegram, то, т.к. [Telegram был заблокирован Роскомнадзором в период с 16.04.2018 по 18.06.2020](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_Telegram_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8), вероятнее всего, что компьютеры находились в разных сетях и обслуживались разными провайдерами. Таким образом, один провайдер добросовестно соблюдал закон и не давал Вам достучаться до серверов Telegram, а провайдер, обслуживающий другой компьютер, нет.

Решения подобных проблем:

1. Не пытаться получить доступ к запрещенным ресурсам;
2. Использовать VPN/Proxy.